# Is there a way to make the ICEPush 2.0.0 wicket pushpanel work with wicket 1.5.4?

Tags: java, wicket-1.5, icepush

I'm trying to use the PushPanel class from ICEPush wicket integration, but the wicket classes used appear to have changed and the PushPanel class does not work with wicket 1.5.4. The icepush-wicket.jar was built using wicket-1.4.5 and some of the classes and methods have changed since.

Is there a way to force it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to adapt the code to work with wicket 1.5.4.

Comment: It has now been posted to my public github repository :)

Answer (score 1):

The Wicket integration with ICEpush was experimental, but we would be happy to bring it forward.  Can you show some of the details of the incompatibility here?

Comment: Of course. I'll post again tomorrow. I think it will be a fairly small change to make the update. The interfaces have changed, but not drastically.

Comment: OK here is the error. On trying to instantiate the PushPanel, I get this exception:
    
`Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.icepush.integration.wicket.core.PushPanel.getRequest()Lorg/apache/wicket/Request;
 at org.icepush.integration.wicket.core.PushPanel.<init>(PushPanel.java:66)
 at uk.ac.warwick.collabtex.AsyncCommsPanel.<init>(AsyncCommsPanel.java:17)
 at uk.ac.warwick.collabtex.Editor.<init>(Editor.java:32)
 ... 43 more`

Comment: It appears this is the case because the `org.apache.wicket.Request` class has been moved and no longer exists as an explicit class.